# Axios async/await flow

Tags: async-await, axios

I'm dipping my toe into the waters of Axios and async/await at the same time, and am trying to understand something about the control flow. Is the following legitimate?

```
let loading=true;
(async() => {
  let response = null;
  try {
    response = await axios.get('https://whatever.com/api');
  } finally {
    loading=false;
  }
  if(response){
    //do something with response here
  }
  
  
})();
```

That is, can I count on the request to have returned at the point I am accessing the response variable? I appreciate I could guarantee it is by moving it into the 'try' immediately after the axios get, but then I would have to have the `loading=false` line before it, as well as in 'finally' (or 'catch'). I need to ensure that loading is set to false before any further actions, whether the request succeeds or fails, and I don't want to repeat myself. Maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Now that you have changed the question, the previous solution will not be working correctly. The issue is that the code inside the IIFE will be executed after everything else is finished, so `loading` will never be set to `false` from the perspective of the outside code. (the other code will be executed, and thеn the IIFE. That's because of the event loop). Your best bet is to make the outside code async and await the axios promise.

If you provide the problem details I might be able to help you refactor it.

#### Previous answer

> I need to ensure that loading is set to false before any further actions

Any code after the await is guaranteed to NOT be loading:

```js
(async() => {
  let response = await axios.get('https://whatever.com/api');  
  // the request is finished, the await guarantees that
})();
```

If you need error handling, you can wrap it in a try/catch:

```js
(async() => {
  try {
     let response = await axios.get('https://whatever.com/api');
     // definitely not loading
  }
  catch (e) {
     // definitely not loading, but an error occurred
  }
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, not clear what that means. Are you saying that my code will work correctly? (I do use a try/finally structure, you will note, but don't use catch because looking at the response variable will reveal whether or not there has been an error (i.e., if it is still null or not).

Comment: Your code will work correctly, I just removed the complexity. The first snippet I provided will behave *exactly* as your code, just all the unnecessary variables and ifs are deleted.

Comment: So where do I put `loading=false`? That's my point. It seems that from the way you have it, I would need to have it both following `let response = await...` and in the catch block.

Comment: You don't need that variable, because it's local - it won't escape the IIFE. The code after the line with the `await` in it can't **POSSIBLY EVER** be `loading=true`. That's why I removed it. This is just how async-await behaves.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you mean. Poorly written example on my part. The 'loading' variable should have been defined before (outside) the IIFE. I need to set loading to false before any further actions, whether or not the request completes successfully. My concern is simply how to avoid repeating the 'loading=false' in both execution paths. No big deal, just seems a bit messy.

Comment: Well now it becomes quite messy, the `loading` will be set to `false` at an undefined moment in time from the perspective of the outside code. Generally, when you are writing asynchronous code, everything else also has to behave asynchronously.

Comment: I presume that I could in fact put everything in the finally block. I.e., set 'loading=false' and then test whether or not response is null and proceed accordingly. The use case for this is in Vue.js, incidentally, wanting to display a loading GIF until the point when the request has completed (or failed).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with vue.js component lifecycle, but I would start my research from there.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the Vue lifecycle as such. I was just explaining why I needed to set loading immediately to false.